# Extracting Kerberos Ticket from WCF method OperationContext

Tags: wcf, kerberos, extract

I have a WCF REST-enabled web service using Kerberos authentication.  The OperationContext contains everything I would expect to receive from ADFS.  However, how can I extract the actual Kerberos ticket?  I need this ticket to generate a KerberosReceiverSecurityToken so that I can communicate with ADFS.
Using WireShark I am able to see the ticket at the HTTP level.  Do I need to implement a custom HTTP handler to extract the ticket?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var header in HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers)
{
  string headerVal = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[header];
  if(headerVal.StartsWith("Negotiate"))
  {
    string parts[] = headerValStr.Split(' ');
    string kerberosStr = parts[1];

    //if a header token begins with "YII" its kerberos
    //otherwise its likely NTLM (or other)
    if(kerberosStr.StartsWith("YII"))
    {
      retVal = Convert.FromBase64String(kerberosStr);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```